# Selectively allow other websites to iframe my website

Tags: nginx, iframe, x-frame-options

Other websites embed my website as iframe. However, I want to control which websites are able to do that. I use nginx as my web server. The way to do that for nginx is by using "add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM www.allowurl.com" . However, as [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#browser_compatibility) shows none of the browsers support it. How do I accomplish this in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Set "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors www.allowurl.com;" or even "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors [www.allowurl1.com](http://www.allowurl1.com) [www.allowurl2.com](http://www.allowurl2.com) www.allowurl3.com;". Browsers that support Content Security Policy will ignore X-Frame-Options when the frame-ancestors directive is set. You could still include X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM for older browsers.